# How to add an image icon to a confirmation dialog box?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

The position and size does not matter for now, all I require is to set a custom image icon instead of a default java icon into the dialog box.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
  int x=0;

  // Import Asus logo
  ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon("AsusConfirmation.jpeg");

  // Create user-friendly information message
  int c = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Your grand total is $"+x+"!\nIs this order correct?", "Checkout", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, img3);

  if(c==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

The error I get with this code is that I can't convert the Image into an int, and I remove the int part, then I won't be able to use:

```
if(c==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right method signature. See at the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon)):

```
public static int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
                Object message,
                String title,
                int optionType,
           ->   int messageType,  <-
                Icon icon)
                         throws HeadlessException
```

What you are doing is falling in a different signature that does not give an `Icon`:

```
public static int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
                Object message,
                String title,
                int optionType,
                int messageType)
                         throws HeadlessException
```

But fail to give an `int`, causing the compiler to complain about a type mismatch.

What you have to do is, add the missing `messageType` argument, then you'll match the first method signature.